# Handsontable updating cells crashing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, handsontable

Ive made a simple single column table using Handsontable. I wanted the user to be able to input time in the format hh:mm:ss but I found that seconds was a valid input like 120s = 00:02:00. This is not so good as its difficult with larger times (hours).

There was a function format and unformat time in the numeral.js library, nice, I used it. Only problem is this code causes the browser to go crazy. I wanted to see how many times the code was looping and like one change to a cell causes 18,000 loop cycles, most of the time crashing the browser. Why it calling cellproperties.render so many times O.o!?

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://localhost/handsontable-0.16.0/dist/handsontable.full.css">
<script src="http://localhost/handsontable-0.16.0/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="exampleGrid1" class="dataTable"></div>
<div id="exampleGrid2" class="dataTable"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var data = [
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    ];


function ValueRenderer2(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
        Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

        var a = numeral().unformat(td.innerHTML);

        console.log(a + 'this');
        value = 'test';


          $('#exampleGrid1').handsontable('setDataAtCell', row, 0, a);
 }
var call = 0
var $container = $("#exampleGrid1");

$container.handsontable({
    data: data,
    colHeaders: ['Time'],
    width: 500,
     columns: [
          {
            type: 'numeric',
            format: '00:00:00',
          },
          ],
    cells:   
        function (col, prop) {
            var cellProperties = {};
            cellProperties.renderer = ValueRenderer2;

            call++;
            console.log("the call is on: " + call);
            return cellProperties;
        },
});







});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line in your custom `ValueRenderer2` cell renderer creates an implicit recursion, because `setDataAtCell` forces a full render on the table which in turn calls the `ValueRenderer2` again.

If I get your question right you probably need a custom cell editor, and not a custom renderer. You can read more about editors [here](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.0/tutorial-cell-editor.html).

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. I'm going to sit with the custom cell editor now, thanks for the help!